# Monitoring IIS Applications using Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-vm

I have an Azure hosted IIS server which is hosting maybe 20 websites. I want to monitor all the websites one common application insights. I had installed the Application Insights Agent on the VM following the below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-vm-vmss-apps

I went for the codeless option. But when I look inside the application insights in the live metrics I get the error below:

Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK

Comment: My first question is, is the rest of the logs being populated? Essentially, are all the logs missing or just the live stream?

Comment: Do you see data in the rest of experiences? Only Live Metrics doesn't send data?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT I can 't see any of the metrics